# How can I process this fail?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

File html:

```
<div id="background">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="usr" style="position:fixed;margin-top:180px;margin-left:900px;"><u>Account ID</u>:</label>
        <form action="processlogin.php" method="post" onSubmit="return process_Login()">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your ID in here" class="form-control" id="usr" name="idcuaban" style="position:absolute;width:350px;margin-top:205px;margin-left:900px;">          
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd" style="position:fixed;margin-top:230px;margin-left:900px;"><u>PIN</u>:</label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter your PIN in here" class="form-control" id="pwd" name="passcuaban" style="position:absolute;width:350px;margin-top:255px;margin-left:900px;">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="font-weight:bold;font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;position:fixed;margin-left:1040px;margin-top:310px;width:100px;">Login</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="font-weight:bold;font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;position:absolute;margin-left:1150px;margin-top:310px;width:100px;">Sign Up</button>
         </form>  
     </div>
</div>
```

function process_Login():

```
function process_Login(){
        var c = document.getElementById("usr").value;
        var d = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
        if(c.length==0){
            alert("ERROR: Your ID account is NULL");
            return false;
        }
        else if(isNaN(c)){
            alert("ERROR: Your ID must be number");
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
```

File processlogin.php:

```
<?php
$user = $_POST["idcuaban"];
$pass = $_POST["passcuaban"];
//connect to server
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if(!$con){
    die("cound not connect");
}
//select database
mysql_select_db("db_atmvisual");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_account WHERE account_id='$user' AND account_pin='$pass'");
$row = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($row!=0){
    echo "login sucess";
}
else
    //header('Location:http://loginfail.html');
    echo "Login fail";?>
```

It's quite difficult to describe my problem, I have 2 files, 1 file .html and 1 file .php, when I click button "Login", it'll connect mySQL to process and return result, but when I try to click button Login, it's just show a nothing page, not return result. Yesterday, It's OK but now I don't understand what wrong with it?

Comment: add braces of else

Comment: If you look closely, you see it on line `4` :) @Saty

Comment: Ohh yaa i see it @C0dekid.php Thanks

Comment: show code of `process_Login()` function

Comment: Yes, it's on line 4 :)) sorry if it's quite hard to look

Comment: Try adding
`error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
That way you can see the errors. Can debug it easier.

Comment: Would you like to describe it a bit, pls!

Comment: `mysql_` functions [have died](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) back in 2012. They don't exist in PHP anymore today.

Comment: so what will I do to process it?

Comment: thanks everyone, I found what's my fail, I can't believe with this fail :))